# Semi-discrete probability distribution

Tags: probability, discrete-data

I am somewhat new to statistics, so bear with me.

I have a dataset that contains integer values. I created a model for this dataset such that

```
y(x) = f(x) + c
```

where `f(x)` is my model and `c` is the error in my model. My `f` function is continuous, and therefore `f(x)` is continuous. I am assuming that `c` is noise, and I am trying to compute the distribution of `c`.

The problem is that, while `c` is real-valued, it is not continuous, since it is defined as a discrete value minus a real-value (`c = y(x) - f(x)`, where `y(x)` is an integer).

The histogram of `c` looks like an exponential distribution, except there are spaces in between (this site wouldn't let me upload my image for lack of reputation). My goal is to create a synthetic dataset that is essentially `y(x) = f(x) + c_2`, where `c_2` are random values from the same distribution as `c`. What distribution should I use for this?

EDIT: Here's some more information. My data is a time-series that are essentially the number of times an action occurs in a given time bin (Poisson-like). So I have data `y(t)`, but I have noticed that I can form pretty good estimates from another variable `x`, such that I can form good models using `y(x) = f(x)`. The model is not perfect, however, hence the error term `c`. My goal is to find the distribution of `c` so that I can create an estimated new dataset with an underlying `f(x)` model with the same distribution of noise as the original dataset.

Comment: You should really post a sample of the data you are trying to analyze, as well as give a little more information about where your data is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

If your response is discrete, you rather than express your model as $y(x) = f(x) + c$, you may instead find it better to think in the form $E(y|x) = f(x)$. Then you might for example specify some distribution for $y$ and thereby estimate $f$. For example, you might fit a GLM - say a Poisson or quasi-Poisson model, if you know the form of $f$, or perhaps a GAM if you don't.

As for creating a simulated data set, once you fit your model, you could for example sample from the distribution you used when you fitted, with the mean set to $\hat{f}(x)$ (though this ignores the uncertainty in the estimate of $f$ - that can be taken into account with some additional effort). Or if it suits your circumstance, you could use a bootstrapping scheme (such as resampling the $(x,y)$ pairs.

More details and some suitable example data would help to narrow down a better approach.

My answer ignores the potential for serial dependence from the time-series aspect of your data, so you'd want to assess that, because it is potentially important.